# Is it ok to write almost any unescaped text inside textarea and get it from JS with it's value property?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textarea

I've noticed that inside HTML textarea element I can set almost any default value without escaping and access it from JavaScript through that element node's `value` property like below:
HTML:

```html
<textarea id="txt">
  <h1>A h1 heading</h2>
  <!-- this is comment -->
  <textarea>This is a textarea&lt;/textarea>
</textarea>
```

JS:

```js
console.log(txt.value)
```

JS Output:

```
  <h1>A h1 heading</h2>
  <!-- this is comment -->
  <textarea>This is a textarea</textarea>
```

To print the nested textarea tag I only needed to escape that `<`. If escape all the angle brackets then it also works. But that is too much work.

My question is it the standard behavior? I've found no articles or docs saying about. I looked into [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/). But it seemed too complex. Is it safe to build app assuming it will work like this on all browsers? Can you please give reference to part of the spec that explains this?

Comment: content of a text area is just text ... clearly if you want `</textarea>` inside a textarea, that won't work since the browser will interpret that as the end of the textarea content - the reference is "how HTML works" - and yes, I imagine anything up to `</textarea>` is permissible inside a `<textarea>`